# Reasonable uses for closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Lately, I have been seeing in my companies production code return with closure functions.  Such as `return (function() {...}());`  And I do not like to see this, but I am not an authoritative source. I thought I would ask StackOverflow why and when this good/bad to use.

*** NOTE ***

Say your not concerned about namespace pollution because all of these functions are already in their on closure.

### Example1a:

```
function foo(bar) {
    return {
        x: 1 + bar,
        y: 1 - bar,
        duration: (function() {
            var i = 0,
                len = 5;
            var results = 0;

            for (; i < bar; i++) {
                results += 1 + (results * bar);
            }

            return results;
        }())
    };
}
```

### Example1b:

```
function barProcess(bar) {
    var i = 0;
    var len = 5;
    var results = 0;

    for (; i < bar; i++) {
         results += 1 + (results * bar);
    }

    return results;
}

function foo(bar) {
    return {
        x: 1 + bar,
        y: 1 - bar,
        duration: barProcess(bar)
    };
}
```

### Example1c:

```
function foo(bar) {
    var i = 0;
    var len = 5;
    var results = 0;

    for (; i < bar; i++) {
         results += 1 + (results * bar);
    }

    return {
        x: 1 + bar,
        y: 1 - bar,
        duration: results
    };
}
```

### Observation:

**Example1a:**
The inner function takes advantage of closure if there is a need.

**Example1b:**
In case `barProcess` could require some closure which could make the argument list long and problematic to maintain.

**Example1c:**
There is no extra function creation per invocation.
It is easiest to debug (in my opinion).

Please if someone can give me some technical reasons for why Example a, b, or c should be used that would be fantastic.

---

So, my lame answer did not satisfy me, so I tried this.  [JS Perf Tests](http://jsperf.com/closure-compare).  Which I think to make my observations not too far off.

Comment: This is more suited to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: In my opinion, you use closures when you need to keep a value of something constant, say like in a loop, otherwise most of the time they are not needed. Self executing functions can be handy, when there's no real point in calling an external function etc. ?

Comment: Extra note: when feature detecting a native function, then it only needs to be decided once, rather than each execution, whether you can use that native function or you need to use a shim/alternative function.

Comment: `Example1a` does create a new function in memory upon every execution, which seems to be silly.  Since the value is already closured in the function itself, why do a second function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to choose a clear winner between examples a,b anc c for every simple case.

In the example you give, version (c) is good enough so I would go with it. That said, version (a) keeps the i, len and results veriables in an even tighter scope so it definitely could be a good way to go if you want to keep "x" and "y" more separate from duration "b".

I'm not a fan of splitting things into separate named functions just for organizational or scoping reasons, like you did on example (b), because it tends to make the code more complicated and harder to follow. However, if the barProccess is an actual reuseable abstraction that you can give a clear name for then keeping it separate might be a good idea.

> Say your not concerned about namespace pollution because all of these functions are already in their on closure.

I think you are exagerating a bit here. The inner IFFE is not 100% recommended like the outer IFFE is but restricting scope even more is still perfectly OK and I don't think its worth fighting against your coleagues over it.

Comment: I was assuming your using something like requirejs which all those functions would be closed in the define/require function.

Comment: And Version a is also 3x slower (via the link i provided to jsperf).  That is something to be noted.

Comment: @Michael: Optimization and that needs to be analized in a case by case basis. I am not sure the difference would still be the same if you had a complicated function with lots of function calls instead of your small example (the kind of situation where its worth the trouble of writing code using the version a style).

Comment: that is an excellent point.  Obviously there is more to be tested!

Answer (score 0):

1a: No closure is formed as the outer function, `foo()`, has not returned when the inner function executes. The inner function is an anonymous "self-executing" subroutine. Whereas a self-executing function *can* form a closure, this one neither does nor needs to. This is a slightly "showy" way to structure the code.

1b: No closure is formed as the outer function, `foo()`, straightforwardly calls the named function `barProcess()`, which returns a numeric value, not a function. This approach would be useful if `barProcess()` is also to be called from elsewhere in the code.

1c: No closure is formed. `foo()` comprises a straightforward block of code, which is simple to understand and will certaily do the job. As javascript `for` loops don't have their own scope, `foo()` will simplify to :

```
function foo(bar) {
    for(var i=0, results=0; i<bar; i++) {
         results += 1 + (results * bar);
    }
    return {
        x: 1 + bar,
        y: 1 - bar,
        duration: results
    };
}
```

Comment: I was trying not to simplify on purpose for c (so that people could see the code was identical in all three places)

Comment: This just really restates what i said, but does not answer the 'why' behind it.  When i say why i say it like this:  "Why do you eat?", "Because i am hungry", "no no no, Why do you eat", "Ohh, because as a human if i do not eat my body will start to digest myself and i'll become sleepy."

I am looking for the second type of why, the greater picture why.

Comment: My main point is to help you understand that precisely none of the cases, a/b/c, involves "closure" - a word that appears in your question's title. Next time you want to ask "why", then consider using the that particular interrogative in the question's title rather than giving a condescending lecture in response to someone's well intentioned answer.

Comment: well i am sorry.  I did not realize, especially answer a involves no form of closure.  I must not know what closure is.  Sorry for being condescending.